# Trying to setup rancher on docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, rancher, netstat

rancher run command

```
 docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8090:80 -p 4443:443 rancher/rancher:latest
```

But in my ,localhost gitlab is appearing first so cant get the site ...i hope in netstat no gitlab is running

```
root@ulm-c-25:/home/urolime/Desktop/trainee1/Docker/Rancher# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1249/ruby       
tcp        0      0 172.21.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 172.19.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 172.20.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2456/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 10.10.100.166:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2083/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8014/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3706/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36071         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2084/containerd 
tcp6       0      0 :::2224                 :::*                    LISTEN      1249/ruby       
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      2054/named      
t**cp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2083/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      8014/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::***                    LISTEN      2054/named      
tcp6       0      0 **:::8090**                 :::*                    LISTEN      16076/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 ***:::4443***                 :::*                    LISTEN      16090/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN      3706/dropbox
```

can someone help me in solving this issue ?

Comment: On 8090 port, docker-proxy is running, can u run this application on any other port

Comment: Rancher is running at 8090.. but cannot get into localhost:8090  is redirected to localhost:8443 ...more the local host showing gitlab symbal